# Not able to capture/Extract id generated in response in Post method

Tags: java, rest, django-rest-framework, rest-assured

I am not able to extract ID generated from response, please help, the last 2 lines are having a problem (refer to screenshot)

[image: SCREENSHOT]

```
@Test
public void create() {  
    RestAssured.baseURI= "https://dummy.restapiexample.com";
    String response=given().log().all().header("Content-Type","application/json")
    .body(payload.employee()).when().post("/api/v1/create")
    .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200)
    .header("Server", "Apache").extract().response().asPrettyString();

    System.out.println(response);

    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(response);
    String id = js.get("id");
    System.out.println("id");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `id` is part of `data` object. You got to retrieve the `data` first and then `id`.

As in, `js.get("data.id")`

Comment: the correct would be `js.get("data.id")` without `$` because it's not JsonPath Jayway, it's is Rest-Assured JsonPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the response path method to capture ID from the response like below:

```
Response response = given()
        .header("accept", "application/json")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .body(json)
    .when()
        .post("/pet");
String petId = response.path("id");
```

Where JSON response is like below:

```
{
"id": 9223372036854775807,
"category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Cat"
},
"name": "doggie",
"photoUrls": [
    "string"
],
"tags": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Tag1"
    }
],
"status": "available"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"Id" is presented inside the "Data" Object. "Id" cannot be accessed directly from outside.

```
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(response)
String id = js.get("data.id")
```